# What is the expansion of $(a-b)^{2r} - (c-b)^{2r}$ where r is a rational number?

Tags: algebra-precalculus

While solving a paper, i came across the following equation,
$$\lim_{p\rightarrow 0}\frac {1}{2rp}\int{|y^\prime - y^*|^{2r} - |y-y^*|^{2r}}= \int {2|y-y^*|^{2r-1}z} $$
where $y^\prime=y+pz.$

I don't how this equality came. Is there any identity for $(a-b)^{2r} - (c-b)^{2r}$ where r is a rational number?

Any hint would be greatly helpful....

Comment: Any idea please?

Comment: Be patient, your question has only been up for a few minutes. Also, what do rational numbers of the form $n/(n-2)$ have to do with anything? It looks to me like if the equation holds, it should hold for a continuum of values of $r$, not just for rational ones, let alone very special rational ones.

Comment: Makes me think of something that Chebychev proved for integrating $x^r$ in finite terms.

Comment: This is just using the definition of derivative:
$\lim_{p \to 0} \frac{f(y+p) - f(y)}{p} = f'(y)$.

Comment: @RobertIsrael but there's a pz. How to deal with it?

Comment: @marty cohen Thank you for the response. But how is that chebyshev expansion related? Can you expand a bit please?

Comment: Let $h = pz$. If $z \ne 0$, $\lim_{p \to 0} \frac{f(y+pz) - f(y)}{p} = z \lim_{h \to 0} \frac{f(y+h)-f(y)}{h} = z f'(y)$.